# Identifying if macro is an alias

Tags: conditionals

I use a `def` as an alias like so:

```
\def\alias{\foo}
```

later on I would like to check if `\alias` is an alias for foo. (X is an alias of Y means the current definition of X is `def\X{\Y}`).

See the MWE below for what I tried:

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{trace}
\def\foo{bar}
\def\bar{bar}

\newcommand{\isFoo}[1]{
%   \expandafter\if\expandafter\noexpand\alias\noexpand\foo  %false positives
%   \expandafter\ifx\alias\foo                               %this one compares text
%   \expandafter\ifx\expandafter\noexpand\alias\noexpand\foo %false negatives
        It is a \textbackslash foo #1
    \else
        Not a \textbackslash foo #1
    \fi
}
\begin{document}
    \def\alias{\foo}
    \isFoo{ab}

    \def\alias{\bar}
    \isFoo{xy}

    \def\bar{baz}
    \isFoo{xy}
\end{document}
```

The idea behind the `expandafter`/`noexpand` code is to expand `\alias` exactly once and then compare the two tokens without any further expansion to avoid comparing their return values.

Comment: I don't think I understand... You want to check if `\alias` expands to `\foo` without comparing if the contents of `\foo` using, for example, `\expandafter\ifx\alias\foo`?

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik this is not fail proofed: `\def\foo{\bar}\def\bar{A}\def\baz{A}\expandafter\ifx\foo\baz true\else false\fi` yields true, though it should yield false.

Comment: @Skillmon Makes sense... If OP had replied I would've done something similar to your approach, but using `\string` and `\ifx` instead of `\detokenize` and `\pdf@strcmp`, but then I forgot :P

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik: Op disappeared from the keyboard for a while,...
but in my simple case what you described did not work (see Skillmon's comment) which lead me to try getting `noexpand` in the mix.

Comment: @ted No problem :) Good that OP's problem is solved ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also just set up another alias for `\foo` and compare `\alias` to that with `\ifx`.

```
\documentclass{article}

% \def\foo{bar}
% \def\bar{bar}

\def\knownaliasforfoo{\foo}
\newcommand{\isFoo}[1]{%
  \ifx\alias\knownaliasforfoo
    It is a \textbackslash foo #1%
  \else
    Not a \textbackslash foo #1%
  \fi
}

\begin{document}
    \def\alias{\foo}
    \isFoo{ab}

    \def\alias{\bar}
    \isFoo{xy}

    \def\bar{baz}
    \isFoo{xy}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can uncomment either or both of the commented lines and the output would remain the same.

Answer (score 4):

The following should do what you want.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{pdftexcmds}

\def\alias{\foo}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\checkalias[2]
  {%
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
    \checkalias@a\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
      {\expandafter\detokenize\expandafter{#1}}{#2}%
  }
\newcommand\checkalias@a[2]
  {%
    \expandafter\ifnum
    \expandafter\pdf@strcmp\expandafter{\detokenize{#2}}{#1}=0
      \expandafter\@firstoftwo
    \else
      \expandafter\@secondoftwo
    \fi
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\checkalias{\alias}{\foo}
  {still an alias}{no longer an alias}
\def\alias{\bar}
\checkalias{\alias}{\foo}
  {still an alias}{no longer an alias}
\end{document}
```

It doesn't check whether the first argument would grab any arguments though and is therefore not as safe as @egreg's check. I don't think it is worth it implementing the necessary checks without expl3 though.

Answer (score 4):

With `expl3`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\ifisaliasTF}{mmmm}
 {% #1 = token to test
  % #2 = macro
  % #3 = true case
  % #4 = false case
  \ted_ifisalias:nnTF { #1 } { #2 } { #3 } { #4 }
 }

\prg_generate_conditional_variant:Nnn \tl_if_empty:n { f } { T,F,TF,p }
\prg_generate_conditional_variant:Nnn \tl_if_single:n { o } { T,F,TF,p }

\prg_new_conditional:Nnn \ted_ifisalias:nn { T,F,TF,p }
 {
  \token_if_macro:NTF #1
   {% the first argument is a macro
    \tl_if_empty:fTF { \token_get_arg_spec:N #1 }
     {% the macro has no arguments
      \tl_if_single:oTF { #1 }
       {% the expansion is a single token
        \exp_last_unbraced:No \token_if_eq_meaning:NNTF #1 #2
         {% the first level expansion of #1 is the same as #2
          \prg_return_true:
         }
         {% false
          \prg_return_false:
         }
       }
       {% false
        \prg_return_false:
       }
     }
     {% false
      \prg_return_false:
     }
   }
   {% false
    \prg_return_false:
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\foo}{Whatever}
\newcommand{\alias}{\foo}
\newcommand{\notaliasA}[1]{\foo}
\newcommand{\notaliasB}{\foo\foo}

\begin{document}

\ifisaliasTF{\alias}{\foo}{Alias}{Not alias}

\ifisaliasTF{\foo}{\foo}{Alias}{Not alias}

\ifisaliasTF{\notaliasA}{\foo}{Alias}{Not alias}

\ifisaliasTF{\notaliasB}{\foo}{Alias}{Not alias}

\end{document}
```

[image]